# segmentation error in program to compare two rational number by using structures and structure function

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

struct  rational{  
  int numerator;
  int denominator;
};


bool equal(struct rational *rational_number1,struct rational *rational_number2);

 void reduce(struct rational *inputrational,struct rational *outputrational);


int main()

{

int p,q,r,s;


printf("details of number 1\n");

printf("numerator\n");

scanf("%d",&q);

printf("denominator\n");

scanf("%d",&p);

printf("details of number 2\n");


printf("numerator\n");

scanf("%d",&s);

printf("denominator\n");

scanf("%d",&r);

struct rational *rationalnumber1,*rationalnumber2;

rationalnumber1->denominator=p;

rationalnumber1->numerator=q;

rationalnumber2->denominator=r;

rationalnumber2->numerator=s;


if(equal(rationalnumber1,rationalnumber2))

printf("both are equal");

else 

printf("both are unequal");

}

bool equal(struct rational *rational_number1,struct rational *rational_number2)


{

struct rational *inputrational1,*inputrational2;

inputrational1=rational_number1;

inputrational2=rational_number2;

struct rational *outputrational1;

struct rational *outputrational2;

outputrational1->numerator=0;

outputrational1->denominator=0;

outputrational2->numerator=0;
outputrational2->denominator=0;

reduce(inputrational1,outputrational1);
reduce(inputrational2,outputrational2);
if(outputrational1==outputrational2)
return true;

}


void reduce(struct rational *inputrational,struct rational *outputrational)


{


int i,f;

for(i=1;(i<=inputrational->numerator)&&(i<=inputrational->denominator);i++)
{

    if((inputrational->numerator%i==0)&&(inputrational->denominator%i==0))
{

    f=i;
}


outputrational->numerator=(inputrational->numerator)/f;

outputrational->denominator=(inputrational->denominator)/f;


}

}
```

Comment: *outputrational IS POINTER TO STRUCTURE RATIONAL WHICH STORE RATIONAL NUMBER IN LOWEST FORM

Comment: *inputrational IS POINTER TO STRUCTURE RATIONAL WHICH STORE RATIONAL NUMBER IN ORIGINAL FORM

Comment: You should be explaining these things in the question and try to shorten the title and give more detailed explanation in the question

Comment: This question does not meet quality requirements for this site: code only, no context, no clear question, no error message *in the question*... You really should read [ask] and edit your question.

Comment: Hint: learn how to format C code properly

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please DO NOT SHOUT in your comments. Also please put an actual question into your question. And please improve your code indentation and general formatting. It is hard to read.

Comment: In general this is a good time to start learning how to debug. With such a simple program you will be able to see the location of your crash very soon.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared pointers to the structure but you have not allocated memory to them.
`struct rational *rationalnumber1,*rationalnumber2;`
`rationalnumber1->denominator=p;`

You have to allocate memory as follows:
`struct rational *rationalnumber1 = malloc(sizeof(*rationalnumber1));`
 before you write the following statement:
`rationalnumber1->denominator=p;`
You have to do it for rationalnumber2 as well.

While we are at it, you don't really need to declare pointers.
You can declare objects to the structure.
You can pass the address of the objects defined to the functions you have defined.